# Convert csv high-frequency data to xts

Tags: r, csv, xts

I am trying to convert [high frequency csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r75XX.png) to xts in order to use features of highfrequency package in R. I try to proceed like this:

```
datadestination = "~/xts_data" 
datasource = "~/raw_data" 
from = "1991-01-02"
to = "2015-12-31"  
convert(from=from, to=to, datasource=datasource, datadestination=datadestination,trades=TRUE,quotes=FALSE, ticker="FV", dir=TRUE, extension="csv",header=TRUE,tradecolnames = c("Date","Time","Close","Volume"),format="%m/%d/%Y,%H:%M",onefile=TRUE)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "COND", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3544456
```

Can anybody help to solve it?

Comment: Share some data to make this reproducible.

Comment: Excerpt from the data here https://www.dropbox.com/s/uav641wn1tj04tg/FV_trades.csv?dl=0